# Reference custom resource path from the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I would like to call a custom controller method "load" from the view. I am struggling to understand how I should call the path to call in the view. In my routes.rb I have the following code:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :merchants_files, except: [:edit] do
    member do
      post 'load', :as => :load
    end
  end
```

In the merchants_files_controller.rb controller I have an action:

```
def load    
    CSV.foreach(@merchants_file.merchants_csv, headers: true, col_sep: ";") do |merchant|
      Merchant.create!(merchant.to_hash)
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to merchants_files_url, notice: "Merchants loaded." }
    end    
  end
```

In the show view I try to reference the correct path to load action:

```
<p style="color: green"><%= notice %></p>

<%= render @merchants_file %>

<div>
  <%= link_to "Back to merchants files", merchants_files_path %>
  <%= button_to "Load the merchants file", merchants_file_load_path, method: :post %>
  <%= button_to "Destroy this merchants file", @merchants_file, method: :delete %>
</div>
```

I have tried different path names other than **merchants_file_load_path**, but I always get an error that the variable with this name does not exist. How should I reference custom path from the view? I struggle to understand how I can properly register custom controller action and reference it with a custom path variable in the view.

I am using Rails 7.0.6

Answer (score 1):

I have found it out myself. First I simplified routes code to:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :merchants_files, except: [:edit] do
    member do
      post :load
    end
  end
```

Second, this is my working view:

```
<p style="color: green"><%= notice %></p>

<%= render @merchants_file %>

<div>
  <%= link_to "Back to merchants files", merchants_files_path %>
  <%= button_to "Load the merchants file", load_merchants_file_path, method: :post %>
  <%= button_to "Destroy this merchants file", @merchants_file, method: :delete %>
</div>
```

I like how it feels writing rails code - it's almost like writing text in English